# Collection in query strings in ASP.NET Core ApiController without using FromQuery(Name = "")

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, collections, query-string, asp.net-core-webapi

I found ASP.NET Core's binding inconsistent.

```
public IActionResult Do(string foo, int bar) // works
public IActionResult DoWithArray(int[] bars) // 415
public IActionResult DoWithDTO([FromQuery] DTO dto) // works
public IActionResult DoWithAttribute([FromQuery] int[] bars) // 415
public IActionResult DoWithAtrributeName([FromQuery(Name = "bars")] int []bars) // works
```

Method "Do" works as exptected. However method "DoWithArray" returns 415. When the array is placed in DTO and the DTO it gets bound fine (even though I am not specifying the Name). Mehtod "DoWithAttribute" doesnt work and if and only if the Name is specified the array gets bound.

I was trying to find out reason for this inconsistency. I found no explanation. Maybe I am doing it wrong or I am thinking about it wrong. Is there something that I am not realizing? Is this correct behaviour? Is there a way hot to bind a collection without using FromQueryAttribute without Name or wihout FromQuneryAttribute at all?

I have not tested if the behaviour get more logical without ApiControllerAttribute.

Edit: Query string of colection is in this format `/api/foo?bars=5&bars=10`

Edit2: In ASP.NET WebApi you could use `FromUriAttribute` like

```
public HttpResponseMessage DoWithArray([FromUri] int[] bars)
```

that would succesfuly bind the array withou specifiying the Name

Comment: We need to know how you're calling this, i.e. the query string you're passing.

Comment: @ChrisPratt added in Edit

Comment: What happens if you do `?bars[]=5&bars[]=10`, mirroring more what you'd get from a post. Does the non-name attribute version work then?